# Temimos Thiyenah

Tags: passover, shavuos, zemanim, maariv

On Shavous by Night we wait and daven Marriv late in order to have Temmimos,Why dont we daven early on the second night of Pesach for the same reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On Shavous by Night we wait and daven Marriv late in order to have Temimos"

Some do this, as per what the Taz, who lived about three hundred fifty years ago, said.

However, not everyone accepted this chiddush of the Taz, and there are kehillos that daven early at the beginning of Shavuos, especially Yekkishe kehillos.

See extensive, very comprehensive discussion on this in the sefer Shorshei Minhag Ashkenaz, volume IV.

Comment: Wow I was unaware of that But Yekkis always have a thing with  time.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

The sefira is not dependent on the Maariv. Maariv on the night of Shavuos implies that the day of Shavuos has started and we do not want that to happen until we have "temimos" (completion) regarding the weeks/days of the omer leading up to Shavuos.

Starting Maariv early for the second day of Pesach does not imply that the first day of sefira has started. The "Days of Sefirah" period starts on its own at nightfall.

Answer (score 0):

Davening ma'ariv on the first night of Shavuot implies that the first day of Shavuot has started (already), and therefore that the last day of sefira has ended. If you start Shavuot early, you end sefira with an incomplete day.

Davening ma'ariv on the second night of Pesach implies that the second day of Pesach (the first night of the Omer) has started already. Even if you daven really late, the first day of sefira has already started naturally at tzait. If you daven early (which may get into issues of the nature of Yom Tov which I'm won't discuss here), then maybe you could be starting sefira early. That doesn't take away from temimot, because you're adding extra time. (I think many are machmir to count only after tzait anyway.)